# Blank project gives errors while uploading Arduino Leonardo on Linux Manjaro

Tags: arduino-leonardo, uploading

I'm on Linux Manjaro. I plugged my Arduino Leonardo clone (that I know works correctly). And tried to flash a blank project on it:
(My IDE version is `1.8.12`)

```c
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

It gives me this error:

```c
Sketch uses 3410 bytes (11%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28672 bytes.
Global variables use 149 bytes (5%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2411 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2560 bytes.
processing.app.debug.RunnerException
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:152)
    at cc.arduino.UploaderUtils.upload(UploaderUtils.java:77)
    at processing.app.SketchController.upload(SketchController.java:732)
    at processing.app.SketchController.exportApplet(SketchController.java:703)
    at processing.app.Editor$UploadHandler.run(Editor.java:2047)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: processing.app.SerialException: Error touching serial port '/dev/ttyACM1'.
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:107)
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:136)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - /dev/ttyACM1; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Permission denied.
    at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:170)
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:101)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: The TL;DR of this overly verbose error message is “/dev/ttyACM1: Permission denied”.

Comment: Im currently reinstalling Arduino IDE (with my bad internet its gonna take a few minutes). So should I try to start Arduino IDE in `sudo`?

Comment: See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/search?q=Linux+permission+denied

Comment: Join the correct group(s). Give your user the correct permissions. Then reboot and try again.

Comment: this is a textbook example of what a question should look like ... minimal code, full error message printout ... a question asking how to determine the cause of the error, or asking what usually causes the error, or asking how to decode the error printout would complete the post .... i think that it deserves an upvote even though the question has been asked before

Comment: @jsotola lol thanks
I will post teh exact answer how to repair it for my distro tomorrow coz today I have no more time to play with arduino

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux#toc6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found a way to do this.
Open Terminal and type:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM*
```

you will get something like:

`crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 5 apr 23.01 ttyACM0`

The "0" at the end of ACM might be a different number, or multiple entries might be returned. The data we need is `dialout` (is the group owner of the file).

Now we just need to add our user to the group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout <username>
```

So for me that would be:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout john
```

BUT it seems to work with `dialout` on ubuntu/debian based distros. I am on `Manjaro` and instead of `dialout` I had to use `uucp` (and in general on `Arch` based distros) so:

```
sudo usermod -a -G uucp john
```

You will need to log out and log in again for this change to take effect.

This is the procedure to access the serial port from the Arduino Software (IDE) if you get an error

After this procedure, you should be able to proceed normally and upload the sketch to your board or use the Serial Monitor.

Although for me that wasn't over. After doing this the only error I got was Arduino IDe simply saying that it doesn't have permission to write to that port. So I had to start `Arduino IDE` by:

```
sudo arduino
```

in the terminal. After that everything works just fine.

I found help at those links:

- https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux#toc6
- https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-enable-putty-usb-serial-converter-access-without-sudo/82736